# Does the discrete log assumption hold if k > p

Tags: discrete-logarithm, elgamal-encryption

In discrete log cryptosystems like ElGamal it is noted that the "private key" $k$ should be chosen as any element of the group $G$ i.e. $k < p-1$. Does the integrity of the cryptosystem rely on $k$ being an element of the group or can it be larger as well (always assuming that $g^k \bmod{p}$ will be published in the public key)? If yes, can it be *any* arbitrarily selected number larger than the group?

Comment: If $k>p-1$ then it is functionally and security-wise fully equivalent to $k\bmod (p-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have chosen a large $k > p$, then one can show that $k'$ with

$$k = \ell \cdot (p-1)+ k' $$ can also be your equivalent key.

From [Euler's Totient Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), we know that $$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \bmod n$$ for all $a$ relatively prime to $n$.

If your key $k> p-1$ then we can write it like below with division algorithm - division by $p-1$;

$$k = \ell\cdot (p-1)+ k' = \ell \cdot \phi(n)+ k'$$ Now place this into $a$'s power and use the Euler's Toitent Theorem:

$$a^k \equiv a^{\ell \cdot \phi(n)+ k'} \equiv a^{\ell \cdot \phi(n)} a^{k'} \equiv \underbrace{a^{(\phi(n))\ell}}_{\equiv 1 \bmod p} a^{k'} \equiv a^{k'} \bmod p$$

Therefore we have

$$a^{k'} \equiv a^k \bmod p$$ and by using $k$ you will not achieve any higher security, contrary you will calculate unnecessarily steps in modular powering.

If you want to achieve more security, you should use a larger modulus.